# What can I do about these errors? Can I restart the program to try again?

Tags: python, exception, runtime-error, k-means

I have a program that gets a datafile of csv's from the command line, along with an integer value for clutering (This is a K-Means program from scratch). I have been running into these errors alot:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "NewK.py", line 73, in <module>
    kMeans(centroids,dataPoints)
  File "NewK.py", line 53, in kMeans
    CentroidMeans.append(np.mean(dataPoints[t2 == [x]], axis=0))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2942, in
mean
    out=out, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 68, in _mean

    ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

and this "Mean of an Empty Slice:"

```
C:\Python27>python NewK.py iris.txt 3
Points in data set:  150
Dimensionality of Data:  (150, 4)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:59: RuntimeWarning: Mean of
 empty slice.
  warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice.", RuntimeWarning)
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:68: RuntimeWarning: invalid
 value encountered in true_divide
  ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
```

It does not happen every time, but it does happen frequently. What would be the best way to deal with this? Yes this is homework :)

Python code:

```
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint
import random
import sys
import warnings

arglist = sys.argv 

NoOfCentroids = int(arglist[2])

dataPointsFromFile = np.array(np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1], delimiter = ','))

dataRange = ([])

with open(arglist[1]) as f:
    print 'Points in data set: ',sum(1 for _ in f)

dataRange.append(round(np.amin(dataPointsFromFile),1))
dataRange.append(round(np.amax(dataPointsFromFile),1))
dataRange = np.asarray(dataRange)

dataPoints = np.array(dataPointsFromFile)
print 'Dimensionality of Data: ', dataPoints.shape

randomCentroids = []
data = ([])
templist = []
i = 0

while i<NoOfCentroids:
    for j in range(len(dataPointsFromFile[1,:])):
        cat = round(random.uniform(np.amin(dataPointsFromFile),np.amax(dataPointsFromFile)),1)
        templist.append(cat)
    print '\n'
    randomCentroids.append(templist)
    templist = []
    i = i+1

centroids = np.asarray(randomCentroids)

def kMeans(array1, array2):
    ConvergenceCounter = 1
    keepGoing = True
    StartingCentroids = np.copy(centroids)
    while keepGoing:      
        #--------------Find The new means---------#
        t0 = StartingCentroids[None, :, :] - dataPoints[:, None, :]
        t1 = np.linalg.norm(t0, axis=-1)
        t2 = np.argmin(t1, axis=-1)
        #------Push the new means to a new array for comparison---------#
        CentroidMeans = []
        for x in xrange(len(StartingCentroids)):
            CentroidMeans.append(np.mean(dataPoints[t2 == [x]], axis=0))
        #--------Convert to a numpy array--------#
        NewMeans = np.asarray(CentroidMeans)
        #------Compare the New Means with the Starting Means------#
        if np.array_equal(NewMeans,StartingCentroids):
            print ('Convergence has been reached after {} moves'.format(ConvergenceCounter))
            print ('Starting Centroids:\n{}'.format(centroids))
            print ('Final Means:\n{}'.format(NewMeans))
            print ('Final Cluster assignments: {}'.format(t2))
            for x in xrange(len(StartingCentroids)):
                print ('Cluster {}:\n'.format(x)), dataPoints[t2 == [x]]
            for x in xrange(len(StartingCentroids)):
                print ('Size of Cluster {}:'.format(x)), len(dataPoints[t2 == [x]])
            keepGoing = False
        else:
            ConvergenceCounter  = ConvergenceCounter +1
            StartingCentroids =np.copy(NewMeans)

kMeans(centroids, dataPoints)
```

Comment: The latter is a warning, not an error. And the former is a `KeyboardInterrupt`, are you pressing ctrl-c?

Comment: Yeah I'm using `Keyboard Interrupt` because the program will just stall if I don't sometimes. Do you know of anything to help?